# How to smoothly upgrade MarkLogic from Windows Server 2013R2 to Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows, marklogic

From the ML admin course, it is taught that ML DB backup heavily rely on the underlying **Host OS**. It is not possible to use backup ML DB and restore ML DB from one Host OS to another Host OS. For example, it is not possible to do that ML migration from **Windows** to **Centos**. I want to check **whether it is possible to do that type of Host OS upgrade in the same OS family with DB back and restore**.

The particular question is for my current ML running on Windows 2013R2. The Windows OS is approaching end of its extended support. How to migrate ML running on it with 1T of data to the latest Windows OS easily?

One way I could think of is to use **MLCP** to migrate all the data from the Old ML to the New ML. Any sample mlcp project to do exactly like that "Apple to Apple" copy? Any side effect?
Another way is to back up and restore ML DB. That is the reason behind the above quesiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the issue is restoring a backup from another OS family, not a specific version of an OS.

Restoring a Windows backup from 2013R2 into Windows Server 2019 should be fine (though you might want to open a Support case with MarkLogic and get confirmation and/or test to be 100% certain).